# Running jar as a Windows service with nssm

Tags: java, windows, jar, windows-services, nssm

I am trying to run a jar (spring app) as a Windows service. I am using [nssm](https://nssm.cc/) to do so.

When I run the jar file with `java -jar myjar.jar` everything works fine. My webapp responds when I enter localhost:8080 where it runs.

After I run

```
nssm install MyService java -jar myjar.jar
nssm start MyService
```

I get in the console: `MyService: START: The operation completed successfully`

My application is usually logging to file as well, but it does not do so when running as a service. It seems like the application is not starting at all. When I try to access localhost:8080, nothing is responding.

Why isn't my app running when I start it as a service with nssm?

Comment: Have you tried using a fully qualified path for the jar in the `nssm install ... ` command?

Comment: Do you need to set the port number? nssm install MyService java –jar <path-to-jar>\myjar.jar –d <installation-path> –p <your port>. And can you also run nssm status <servicename> to see a status code?

Comment: What does the nssm log say?